# Android, get location of text where user touched/clicked

Tags: android

I have a TextView with a paragraph of text.  I am trying to retrieve the point (index, maybe) of where the user touched/clicked on the text. Something along the lines of:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      TextView txt = (TextView)v;

      // magic here...
      index = ...
      
   }
});
```

The idea is to then programmatically select a specific portion of the text (which I can already do).  I need to build in logic so that a very specific is selected without the user worrying about where the start and where to end.

Comment: Did you try using `mTextView.getSelectionStart()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement onTouchListener for this. Here is sample code:

```
txt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();
            
            // Do stuff with x and y
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This feels a bit cumbersome, given that they view might have scrolled, font sizes, etc.  I was thinking of doing something like this, but thought there may be a better method.